# umbraco.library get nodename but string utf-8 show wrong

Tags: c#, utf-8, umbraco

I get nodename like this:

```
string text = umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().Name;
```

but it shows like this:

```
BETON KÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬â€œÃƒâ€¦Ã‚ÂK
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: well, what *should* it be? also: if you are simply using the inbuilt library, I would suggest this is a bug to be logged with umbraco / library provider, rather than a programming question for stackoverflow

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 0):

GetCurrent().Name should return a string

(http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/working-with-nodefactory)

So if your string looks like that either your encoding is not set to utf-8 or your App_Data\umbraco.config file is corrupt.

The NodeFactory methods are basically a facade in front of the umbraco.config file - so have a look in that file to see if it is corrupted.  The umbraco.config file is an xml file so also check that the first line is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Secondly check your web.config for the encoding:

```
<system.web>
<globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Thirdly check all your Umbraco \config*.config files (which are all xml files) and make sure that the first line is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```